# input field data compare to DB and display another values of db

Tags: php, mysql

I have four column in database .in html has two field if I type  two fields then it compare the DB and if same when display another two column value .how its work in php
in a input field i type apple and orange its compare Db and display mango grape
and apple1 and orange1 its display mango1 grape1  how?

ex if my db is 
apple orange mango grape ,
apple1 orange1 mango1 grape1
apple2 orange2 mango2 grape2

i want to compare the input text from the user to db.the input data how to compare DB and display the same row  another values..please help me

Comment: in returning values from db give col(2) instead of col(1).That is select col2 from tble where like col1=value. col1 contains  apple , and col2 contains apple1 .

Comment: how i am starter in php

Comment: what you tried upto this

Comment: i like to create if i am typing username and password its display same person address and phone number every data stored in db..please help me

Comment: hey use javascript ajax function to call php function and get the value what you want?. or you need sample program?

Comment: yes.only php is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I just give sample code

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
Name1 : <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="" > </br>
Name2 : <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name2" name="name2" value="" ></br>

<script type="text/javascript">
               $( document ).ready(function() {
                    $('#name').blur(function(){
                     var name=$("#name").val();
                     $.ajax({
                                type: "post",
                                url: "ajax_get_sub",
                                cache: false,
                                data: {name:name},
                                success: function(plan){        
                                try{        
                                     $("#name2").val(plan);
                                }catch(e) {     
                                    alert('Exception while request..');
                                }   

                                },
                                error: function(e){                     
                                    alert('Error while request..');
                                }

                            });
                    });
               });
               </script>
```

And PHP Function like this. File name:ajax_get_sub

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) 
    {
    $t=$this->input->post('name');
    $result=$this->db->query("select * from table where col1 LIKE '%{$t}%'");
    $result->num_rows();
    foreach($result->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $name = $row['col2'];
    }
    echo $name;
    }
```